# Tick vals with plotly in 3D diagram

Tags: javascript, plotly

I've been trying to get tick vals to work on 3D diagram, is it possible? 
I tried to set tickmode to array, but I guess it is set automatically if tickvals is provided. See the plnkr below.

```
tickmode: 'array',
tickvals: [...]
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/IDlCmBvzFXucvPpuiAX7?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to wrap your xaxis and yaxis with [`ticktext`](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#layout-scene-zaxis-ticktext) and [`tickvals`](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#layout-scene-zaxis-tickvals) in a [`scene`](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#layout-scene).
`tickvals` are actually the values which are used for the ticks while `ticktext` is the shown label. Your updated code is here:

https://plnkr.co/edit/YnfTS9uoFBiCRTPi36Kt?p=preview

```js
z1 = [
  [8.83, 8.89, 8.81, 8.87, 8.9, 8.87],
  [8.89, 8.94, 8.85, 8.94, 8.96, 8.92],
  [8.84, 8.9, 8.82, 8.92, 8.93, 8.91],
  [8.79, 8.85, 8.79, 8.9, 8.94, 8.92],
  [8.79, 8.88, 8.81, 8.9, 8.95, 8.92],
  [8.8, 8.82, 8.78, 8.91, 8.94, 8.92],
  [8.75, 8.78, 8.77, 8.91, 8.95, 8.92],
  [8.8, 8.8, 8.77, 8.91, 8.95, 8.94],
  [8.74, 8.81, 8.76, 8.93, 8.98, 8.99],
  [8.89, 8.99, 8.92, 9.1, 9.13, 9.11],
  [8.97, 8.97, 8.91, 9.09, 9.11, 9.11],
  [9.04, 9.08, 9.05, 9.25, 9.28, 9.27],
  [9, 9.01, 9, 9.2, 9.23, 9.2],
  [8.99, 8.99, 8.98, 9.18, 9.2, 9.19],
  [8.93, 8.97, 8.97, 9.18, 9.2, 9.18]
];
var data_z1 = {
  z: z1,
  type: 'surface'
};
var layout = {
  scene: {
    xaxis: {
      tickvals: [0, 2, 3, 4],
      ticktext: ['Zero', 'Two or lower', 'Three', 'Four and higher']
    }
  }
};
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', [data_z1], layout);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```